antlr case insensitivity is being ignored
For some reason the letter fragments defined in a case-insensitive manner are still case-sensitive:
grammar filter;

query:                      expression? EOF;
expression :                field operator=(LT | LT_EQ | GT | GT_EQ | EQ | NOT_EQ1) value     #comparatorExpression
                            | expression operator=(AND | OR) expression                       #binaryExpression
                            | OPEN_PAR expression CLOSE_PAR                                   #groupedExpression
                            ;

field :                     IDENTIFIER;
value:                      STRING_LITERAL
                            | BOOLEAN
                            | NUMBER
                            ;

NUMBER:                     [0-9,.]+;
STRING_LITERAL:             QUOTE.+?QUOTE;
BOOLEAN:                    (T R U E | F A L S E);

IDENTIFIER :                [a-zA-Z_]+;
OPEN_PAR :                  '(';
CLOSE_PAR :                 ')';
LT :                        '<';
LT_EQ :                     '<=';
GT :                        '>';
GT_EQ :                     '>=';
EQ :                        '=';
NOT_EQ1 :                   '!=';
AND :                       A N D;
OR :                        O R;
SPACES:                     [ \u000B\t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);

fragment DIGIT :            [0-9];
fragment A :                [aA];
fragment B :                [bB];
fragment C :                [cC];
fragment D :                [dD];
fragment E :                [eE];
fragment F :                [fF];
fragment G :                [gG];
fragment H :                [hH];
fragment I :                [iI];
fragment J :                [jJ];
fragment K :                [kK];
fragment L :                [lL];
fragment M :                [mM];
fragment N :                [nN];
fragment O :                [oO];
fragment P :                [pP];
fragment Q :                [qQ];
fragment R :                [rR];
fragment S :                [sS];
fragment T :                [tT];
fragment U :                [uU];
fragment V :                [vV];
fragment W :                [wW];
fragment X :                [xX];
fragment Y :                [yY];
fragment Z :                [zZ];
fragment QUOTE :            ["];

I know there are other solutions, such as doing this on the parsing side of things, but most solutions I found online were pretty much exactly this. However, I always get the error:
line 1:12 mismatched input 'and' expecting {<EOF>, AND, OR}

The respective docs: https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4/blob/master/doc/case-insensitive-lexing.md#case-insensitive-grammars
I have also seen this being used:
options {
    caseInsensitive = true;
}

Docs: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/options.md#caseinsensitive
However, the result seems to be the same.

Dump the token stream.  Likely your and is matching as an IDENTIFIER, not AND as you expect. Search SO for the many different Qs relating to token stream dumping and lexer rule priority: how Antlr selects between two rules that can both match the same input.

The solution: place IDENTIFIER after AND and OR. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962595/overlapping-tokens-in-antlr-4 as to why.

Thanks a bunch. Guess I didn't quite read enough docs. Never would've guessed that.

It's understandable people fall into that "overlapping tokens" trap.
